# Create a subclass not to repeat matching fields

Tags: python, django

I created two class models in Django. Is there a way not to repeat the same matching fields storing them in a different class or variable?

This is what i got:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.category) + self.slug + " " + str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(str(self.category)) + "/" + slugify(self.title+str(-self.id))
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post2(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.category) + self.slug + " " + str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(str(self.category)) + "/" + slugify(self.title+str(-self.id))
        super(Post2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to find out the [**`abstract`** model class.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

You can create an abstract model class by setting **`abstract=True`**  in the **`Meta`** class of a model.

```
class AbstractPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # common fields and functions

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Post(AbstractPost): # inherit the abstract base class
    pass


class Post2(AbstractPost):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way of passing the functions as well if they reference the model like this `super(Post, self)`

Comment: This model inheritance is just like any other Python classes, which means you will be able to access the methods of parent class by using **`super()`** method. The only difference in *abstract model class*  is this model will not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.